# XCode iOs Builds - Significance of mixing OS versions and SDK versions?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, build

I am wondering what the significance is of doing an iOS 6.0 build, but with the 7.1 SDK. How could a iOS 6.0 phone contain the code for 7.1 features?

Comment: It can't. You will need to check, at runtime, if calls or methods are available.

Comment: What's the difference with running the 6.0 SDK then?

Comment: Well Apple no longer accepts SDK 6 build, so all apps should now be build with SDk 7. You can still make an app you build in iOS SDk 7 run on iOS 6 if you want, but then you should check, at run time, whether a class or method is available.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't, your code must be compatible for ios 6.0 and up. You can not use new features or properties of ios 7.0 in ios 6.0.